# Get all Hidden data available in a image

Tags: php, image

How do I get hidden data available in an image file using PHP.

[hidden data, meaning camera model, location, photo taken date and geocodes etc..]

Is it possible to fetch all of the hidden data using PHP?

Comment: You really need to show that you've tried to answer the question yourself and then let us know in what way it isn't working before you ask a question.

Comment: This data is called **meta data**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php).

Comment: I'd +1 this but all out of votes :( The OP hasn't even Google'd the question (as this would've come up first tbh), so I think this is a suitable answer so the OP can go learn it instead of just getting the code for it. (And sorry Wayne for jacking your answer like that haha)

Comment: @Darren Yea, I was tempted not to answer. However, this question could show up at the top of Google in the future.

Comment: Lets both hope that doesn't happen!

Comment: Thanks wayne. Using exif_read_data functctin i have get image hidden data .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) which will return an array with the data you need. 
The documentation states:

`exif_read_data() reads the EXIF headers from a JPEG or TIFF image file. This way you can read meta data generated by digital cameras.`

Keep in mind that different cameras will use different names for this data:

`EXIF headers tend to be present in JPEG/TIFF images generated by digital cameras, but unfortunately each digital camera maker has a different idea of how to actually tag their images, so you can't always rely on a specific Exif header being present.`

In addition, make sure you have the Exif Extension enabled in your php installation (http://php.net/manual/en/exif.setup.php)